# Exiling tokens with conjurer's closet

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens if you exile a token with [Conjurer's Closet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bConjurer%27s%5d%2b%5bCloset%5d)? My understanding is that the token disappearing is a state based action, which is only checked when the ability finishes resolving. Since the closet exiles and returns the token as part of the resolution of a single ability, state based actions are never checked and the token survives. Is this correct?

Edit: I just noticed that the closet specifically refers to "that card". Does that change the answer?

Comment: If you're asking about Conjurer's Closet and tokens, you should just ask about tokens, and ask a different question about leaves the battlefield triggers.

Comment: Sorry. Should I delete the last two questions?

Comment: I think it's OK to keep both questions about tokens and ask the one that doesn't involve tokens separately.

Comment: Re "*I just noticed that the closet specifically refers to "that card". Does that change the answer?*", "That X" is not a check, but it's an indicator of what the writers expect to be possible. It is sometimes possible (in very rare and unusual circumstances) for "that X" to refer to something that isn't an "X", but that's not intentional. (I think these are usually fixed when found.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The token will disappear, and it will never enter the battlefield.

You are correct that state based actions are only checked after the entire ability resolves. However, there is an additional rule that applies here: [rule 110.5g](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Permanents) says

> A token that has left the battlefield can’t move to another zone or come back onto the battlefield. If such a token would change zones, it remains in its current zone instead. It ceases to exist the next time state-based actions are checked; see rule 704.

So once the token is exiled, it stays in exile even when the Conjurer's Closet instructs you to return it to the battlefield.

So, the use of the phrase "that card" on Conjurer's Closet is not the reason that it only returns to the battlefield if it's a card, but it's a hint that that's how it works anyway.

Comment: "So once the token is exiled, it stays in exile ..." If I read the quoted rules text, it would appear the token never even reaches the 'exile zone' - it just ceases to be. I'm not sure that your sentence is worded most appropriately.

Comment: The rule talks about "a token that **has left the battlefield**". That means that it went to some other zone. And it says that the token can't "**come back** to the battlefield", which again implies that it is in some zone other than the battlefield. More to the point, it says that the token "remains in its current zone", so the token clearly exists in some zone and doesn't just disappear.

Comment: Ah, so you;re saying that it first moves to either the graveyard or the exile-zone, disappears from there on SBA, and can't be re-located in the interim.

Comment: this mostly applies to tokens going to the graveyard as they will still trigger abilites  that state "when <creature type> dies" or "when <permanent type> is destroyed", because they do go to the graveyard before ceasing to exist